How to make an API call for Zendesk Chatbot using Googlesheets as a database
I have an issue I am trying to get customer order information using Googlesheets and I need to make an API call to my Zendesk Chatbot so that it can retrieve customer information from Googlesheets.. I'm stuck I tried using apps script and getting web URL and using it as an endpoint but it's not working on my Zendesk bot.. please help 
I tried to make an API call using the URL I got from Googlesheets but it's not working inside my Zendesk Chatbot.
